# Passar um array para outro formato

Tags: php, mysql, json, array

O array está vindo nesse formato do banco de dados:

```
array (size=12)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'maquinas' => string '111' (length=3)
      'mes' => string '1' (length=1)
      'YEAR(data_ordem)' => string '2016' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'maquinas' => string '99' (length=2)
      'mes' => string '2' (length=1)
      'YEAR(data_ordem)' => string '2016' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'maquinas' => string '116' (length=3)
      'mes' => string '3' (length=1)
      'YEAR(data_ordem)' => string '2016' (length=4)
```

Preciso que ele fique assim:

```
$dados = array(
    array('Janeiro', 10),
    array('Fevereiro', 10),
    array('Março', 10),
    array('Abril', 30),
```

Porém não estou conseguindo.

Comment: E de onde está vindo esses inteiros associados ao mês?

Comment: O mês que está em número vc quer vire por extenso e em português, esse é o problema? aqueles 10 e o 30 eu não faço ideia do que seja.

Comment: Janeiro, Fevereiro, Março e Abril a gente pode deduzir que é o número do mês(resta saber se começa de 0 ou de 1). Agora o 10,10,10,30, como o Marcelo falou, só pelo array de cima não dá para deduzir o que são. Seriam o número de máquinas?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tente isto:

```
$array_meses = array();
$array_meses[1] = "Janeiro";
$array_meses[2] = "Fevereiro";
$array_meses[3] = "Março";
$array_meses[4] = "Abril";
$array_meses[5] = "Maio";
$array_meses[6] = "Junho";
$array_meses[7] = "Julho";
$array_meses[8] = "Agosto";
$array_meses[9] = "Setembro";
$array_meses[10] = "Outubro";
$array_meses[11] = "Novembro";
$array_meses[12] = "Dezembro";

$novo_array = array();

foreach($array_banco as $value)
{
     $novo_array[] = array($array_meses[(int) $value["mes"]], $value["maquinas"]);
}

print_r($novo_array);
```

Comment: Valeu cara, era isso mesmo que precisava! Abraços

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php 

function mesExtenso($mes){
    return [
        1 => 'Janeiro',
        'Fevereiro',
        'Março',
        'Abril',
        'Maio',
        'Junho',
        'Julho',
        'Agosto',
        'Setembro',
        'Outubro',
        'Novembro',
        'Dezembro'
    ][$mes];
}

$data = [
    [
        'maquinas' =>  '111',
        'mes' =>  '1',
        'YEAR(data_ordem)' =>  '2016'
    ],
    [
        'maquinas' =>  '99',
        'mes' =>  '2',
        'YEAR(data_ordem)' =>  '2016'
    ],
    [
        'maquinas' =>  '116',
        'mes' =>  '3',
        'YEAR(data_ordem)' =>  '2016'
    ]
];

$return = [];

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $return[] = [
        mesExtenso($value['mes']),
        $value['maquinas']
    ];
}

var_dump($return);
```

Retornará:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Janeiro' (length=7)
      1 => string '111' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Fevereiro' (length=9)
      1 => string '99' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Março' (length=6)
      1 => string '116' (length=3)
```

Obs: Como você não mencionou quais são os números associados ao mês, utilizei como exemplo a chave `maquinas`.

[Teste no ideone](http://ideone.com/CmgyUw)

Comment: Poderiam ao menos informar o motivo do `downvote` para que possa ser sanado o problema na resposta, caso tenha.